# Drupal 8 migrate module

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-8, migrate

i'm trying to upgrade from drupal 6 to drupal 8.

I follow all instruction. But i have a problem : when i try to install the migrate module of drupal 8 with the instruction [www.rawcoral.it/upgrade](http://www.rawcoral.it/upgrade) , it give me "page not found" .

I'm using a fresh Drupal 8 installation. I've installed modules: Migrates, Migrate Drupal and Migrate Drupal UI . 
All was done without problem.

I really don't know what is wrong. My website is on OVH and i'm using PLESK .

Comment: You say that you have problem with installing migrate module, but then you say you installed without a problem?!

Comment: As I already sayed, I installed withou problem but when I try to use it with http://www.rawcoral.it/upgrade , it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When I open the URL : http://www.rawcoral.it/upgrade[image]

It is related to database connection credentials.

Please provide proper credentials of mysql in settings.php

Comment: Yes its related to db credentials. Please check your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you should have both database / d8 db setting will be in settings .php

and d6 db name will be in migration module setting in you d8 setting